# save in own format imagej or imagej2

Tags: game-development, imagej, writefile

I am participating in the development of a real time strategy game named [0ad](https://play0ad.com/). When it comes to map-making one of the coolest options is using real topographic data in image files and convert them to a heightmap own format. The problem is that it allows 16-bit (65536) heights whereas it only allows 8-bit files as import. Apparently it is not easy to fix this in its code, so I want to write a script (preferably) or a plugin in ImageJ (or ImageJ2) in order to convert a 16-bit grayscale image directly into a heightmap.

- Is this possible with a script? (Prefer Python or Javascript) I have found no clue how to save an arbitrary binary file to write this own format.
- If a plugin is a must, then: where to start and how the files are saved given this is not a standard image?

The technical [details of the format are defined in C++](https://trac.wildfiregames.com/wiki/PMP_File_Format) (a bit obscure for me as I am not a professional programmer) below:

```
PMP {
 // FILE HEADER
 char magic[4]; // == "PSMP"
 u32 version; // == 6
 u32 data_size; // == filesize-12

 // DATA SECTION
 u32 map_size; // number of patches (16x16 tiles) per side

 u16 heightmap[(mapsize*16 + 1)*(mapsize*16 + 1)]; // vertex heights with lines indexed from
                                                   // bottom to top and columns from left to right
 u32 num_terrain_textures;
 String terrain_textures[num_terrain_textures]; // filenames (no path and file ending), e.g. "cliff1"

 Patch patches[mapsize*mapsize]; // lines indexed from bottom to top, columns from left to right
 }
 
 Patch {
     Tile tiles[16*16];
 }
 
 Tile {
     u16 texture1; // index into terrain_textures[]
     u16 texture2; // index, or 0xFFFF for 'none'
     u32 priority; // Used for blending between edges of tiles with different textures. A higher priority is blended on top of a lower priority.
 }
 
 String {
     u32 length;
     char data[length]; // not NUL-terminated
}
```

Thanks, any help is welcome.

Comment: This request is more related to game-building software than ImageJ. Will say, it is rather unlikely that people involved with the **scientific** image processing software ImageJ are also involved with game-building software and the related file-formats.

Comment: Hi, Herbie, thanks for your comment, however, IMHO from an agnostic file saver perspective it is just a question about saving a non-standard image format in ImageJ and how to accomplish that. Game introduction is just giving some background on the problem and more information if someone needs it or would like to help beyond answering the question (such as writing the plugin). Obviously it could exist a more general question not involving ImageJ, but this is not the case. I use ImageJ and need some help with it. Greetings.

Comment: I fear you need somebody who is acquainted with, or is willing to explore, the file formats in question. Personally and presently, I don't have the capacity to help but I wish you great success with getting in contact with a qualified person.